# How would you know what to do with "Giant's Kinship"?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know what it does, but when does the **plot** tell you what it is and where to use it?

Comment: How do you know what it does?  Did you read it in a walkthrough or something?

Comment: Perhaps a short explanation about where you found the item, would help to improve the question.

Comment: There is only one so where I got it is irrelevant. What is relevant though is that it's far from obvious what to do with the item even though it's crucial to proceed in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get it, the Emerald Herald moves to the stairs leading to the Throne of Want and says the following.

> **When met at the stairs leading to the Throne of Want**: My journey is
>   already complete. My name is Shanalotte. The dragon gave me this name,
>   for I was born with none. I was born of dragons, contrived by men. By
>   ones who would cozen fate herself… They are the ones who created me.
>   But they failed. I did not come out as intended. Fate would not be
>   bested, and men were cursed once again. **If you proceed, Nashandra will
>   come after you. Knowing that you will take the throne, and link the
>   fire.** She covets the First Flame, and the Great Soul. Put Nashandra to
>   rest.

http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/emerald-herald

This does not really tell you what the giant kinship does, but it leads you directly to where you use it and the final confrontation.

There is also the process of elimination: There are 3 doors that require the kings ring to access. At this point in the game, you have already unlocked and gotten a key from 2 of them (the first blocks access to what eventually leads to the Ashen Mist Heart. The second blocks the Giant's Kinship). There is 1 place left, so it is logical to head there.

Comment: It is hard to keep a memory of everything in the game. I had to ask someone else about it 'cos it had been so long since I was near that door. But yes, once I remembered, it made sense.